# Find all files where content is identical in Windows 10 File Explorer search results

Tags: c#, file, search, windows-10, explorer

This sounds like some thing that would have been asked before but I can't find it!

Is there an easy way to find out which files have content that is identical in the results of a Windows 10 File Explorer search results?

I used Windows 10 "File Explorer" to search for a pattern "*V10.xml" in a folder that has many sub-folders, which contain files where the majority of the files will be the same and a small few will have slightly different content.

I want to identify a list of the files that are identical.

I am a C# programmer and know that I could write some code to loop through all the folders and do a hash of the files using a class something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;


namespace VerifyFileData
{
    public class DataComparer
    {
        public bool Compare(
            string expectedFileData,
            string actualFileData)
        {
            var _expectedHashString = this.GenerateHashString(expectedFileData);
            var _actualHashString = this.GenerateHashString(actualFileData);
            return _expectedHashString == _actualHashString;
        }


        private string GenerateHashString(
            string inputString)
        {
            var _hashAsBytes = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputString));

            return _hashAsBytes.AsEnumerable().Aggregate("", (accumulatedString, byteValue) =>
                accumulatedString + byteValue.ToString("X2"));
        }
    }
}
```

I just taught I might be missing a more obvious built in way or tool to do this?

Comment: What type of content do the files contain? Are all of these files of the same datatype?

Comment: These are all XML files as per the search pattern in the question  "*V10.xml" so yes they are all of the same datatype.

Comment: And you dont have any pattern where the files differ? Couldnt you rather iterate with a foreach loop through first the root nodes names and (if still no difference has been found) then the child nodes names and once the expected and actual data differ, you exit the loop?

Comment: Yes I could do that as the only only thing that is different is the value inside some of the child nodes but this is not what this questions is asking. I know how I could do this with C# code. The real question here is, am I missing a more obvious build in way or tool to do this for me rather than writing code to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing i have heard of so far is this [XML diff API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx). It´s basically a tool to compare two xml files.

I should be useful for your purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the link and I appreciate the effort but the question is more generic. I'm not specifically interested in XML. The code in my question could be used for other file types also like CSV, TXT, logs etc. and would tell you if the content of any of these file types are identical. I'm really looking for a list of the file names and path locations for files that have identical content within the many sub-folders of a search result using the Window 10 File Explorer.

Comment: Ok, but that was the reason why i asked you for which specific files you want a solution. ;)

I would not consider myself as an deep C# expert but from my opinion. If you want such a generic algorithm, there is possibly no other way round than your approach for generic comparing. Because which pattern should the algorithm follow? The only thing all files have in common is that you can get some sort of text `string´ for comparison with another. But thats just my opinion.

Comment: I would rather write more specific algorithms for files you know you have a good way for comparison and the one that you didnt have time for or no clue how to do it better than your approach on the top, you go this generic way.